# Is there any logical mistake in my code ? Middleware not showing decoded data from json file from liveserver?

Tags: flutter, async-await, redux-middleware, flutter-redux

I have been following Flutter Redux tutorial from youtube. The same is code is working in tutorial but when I implemented it, it's not working logically. Basically, I am fetching data from json file running on live server on my pc and there is no object display from json on the app. Can anyone suggest what is actually wrong.

Here is the code:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:redux/redux.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_redux/flutter_redux.dart';
    
    const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/people.json';
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    @immutable
    class Person {
      final String name;
      final int age;
      const Person({required this.name, required this.age});
      Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
          : name = json['name'] as String,
            age = json['age'] as int;
    
      @override
      String toString() => 'Person ($name, $age years old )';
    }
    
    Future<Iterable<Person>> getPersons() async => HttpClient()
        .getUrl(Uri.parse(apiUrl))
        .then((req) => req.close())
        .then((resp) => resp.transform(utf8.decoder).join())
        .then((str) => json.decode(str) as List<dynamic>)
        .then((list) => list.map((e) => Person.fromJson(e)));
    
    @immutable
    abstract class Action {
      const Action();
    }
    
    @immutable
    class LoadPeopleAction extends Action {
      const LoadPeopleAction();
    }
    
    @immutable
    class SuccessfullyFetchedPeopleAction extends Action {
      final Iterable<Person> persons;
      const SuccessfullyFetchedPeopleAction({required this.persons});
    }
    
    @immutable
    class FailedToFetchPeopleAction extends Action {
      final Object error;
      const FailedToFetchPeopleAction({required this.error});
    }
    
    @immutable
    class State {
      final bool isLoading;
      final Iterable<Person>? fetchedPersons;
      final Object? error;
    
      const State(
          {required this.isLoading,
          required this.fetchedPersons,
          required this.error});
    
      const State.empty()
          : isLoading = false,
            fetchedPersons = null,
            error = null;
    }
    
    State reducer(State oldState, action) {
      if (action is LoadPeopleAction) {
        return const State(isLoading: true, fetchedPersons: null, error: null);
      } else if (action is SuccessfullyFetchedPeopleAction) {
        return State(isLoading: false, fetchedPersons: action.persons, error: null);
      } else if (action is FailedToFetchPeopleAction) {
        return State(
            isLoading: false,
            fetchedPersons: oldState.fetchedPersons,
            error: action.error);
      }
      return oldState;
    }
    
    void loadPeopleMiddleware(
        Store<State> store, dynamic action, NextDispatcher next) {
      if (action is LoadPeopleAction) {
        getPersons()
            .then((persons) =>
                store.dispatch(SuccessfullyFetchedPeopleAction(persons: persons)))
            .catchError((e) => store.dispatch(FailedToFetchPeopleAction(error: e)));
      }
      next(action);
    }
    
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final store = Store(reducer,
            initialState: const State.empty(), middleware: [loadPeopleMiddleware]);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Center(
              child: Text('Flutter Redux Demo'),
            ),
          ),
          body: StoreProvider(
            store: store,
            child: Column(children: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    store.dispatch(const LoadPeopleAction());
                  },
                  child: const Center(child: Text('Load Persons'))),
              StoreConnector<State, bool>(
                  converter: (store) => store.state.isLoading,
                  builder: (context, isLoading) {
                    if (isLoading) {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    } else {
                      return const SizedBox();
                    }
                  }),
              StoreConnector<State, Iterable<Person>?>(
                  converter: (store) => store.state.fetchedPersons,
                  builder: (context, people) {
                    if (people == null) {
                      return const SizedBox();
                    } else {
                      return Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: people.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final person = people.elementAt(index);
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text(person.name),
                                subtitle: Text('${person.age} years old.'),
                              );
                            }),
                      );
                    }
                  })
            ]),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And here is the people.json file I uploaded on live server.

```
    [{
            "name": "Foo",
            "age": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "Bar",
            "age": 30
        }, {
            "name": "F",
            "age": 20
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get any error messages, exceptions?

Comment: Not any error. But the items in the json file are not displayed.